# Distinguish between upper index and power

Tags: math-mode, formatting, typography, superscripts

I am currently writing the scriptum of our theoretical physics lecture.
I always have trouble with the notation.

Our professor uses lower indices like `m_i` for the i-th mass, upper indices like `\vec{x}^i` to describe the i-th component of x but also `\vec{x}^2=\vec{x}\cdot \vec{x}`.

Is there a way to clearly distinguish these two cases?

Comment: You can use `x^i` instead of `\vec{x}^i` for the vector component

Comment: (Upper) indices are typically distinguished from powers by using brackets. That is, `x^{(2)}` for "the second component of `x`" compared to `x^2` for `x` squared.

Comment: No, there isn't. The notation with upper indices is inherently ambiguous when powers are also used.

Comment: Please be aware about contravariant and covariant indices, i.e. the position indices indicating components can change the meaning of a vector!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer However, you can't, in general, take powers of these beasts. I'm sure we've discussed this thing before and came to the conclusion that this has little to do with LaTeX. It's a problem of mathematicians and their notation.

Comment: @yo: I did not say it's a LaTeX issue.

Comment: @Werner: I also use parentheses to distinguish upper indices, but to save time (as I take notes in LaTeX), I've added `\catcode`\"=13` and `\newcommand*{"}[1]{^{(#1)}}` to my preamble to make this simpler: now, `x"2` gives me `x^{(2)}`. This is also clearly distinct from `x_2` and `x^2` in my code.

Comment: Oh oops! I completely forgot about TeX.SE's markdown. It should have been `\catcode\`\"=13` -- but if that doesn't work, what compiler are you using (LaTeX, XeTeX, etc) and what packages cause it to happen?

Comment: @ArunDebray PdfLatex. Im using inputenc[utf8] babel[german] the AMS packages and tikz/pgf. The babel package seems to cause the trouble

Comment: @meneken17 Aha, it's to do with `babel`. Since you'er using `inputenc`, you can write stuff like ä, ö, and ü directly, so you can instead use `\renewcommand*{\"}[1]{^{(#1)}}` and `x\"2` instead. I tested this with `\usepackage[german]{babel}` and it works.

Comment: @ArunDebray Well that wrecks up my ä by wrinting it as ^{(a)}. I'm gonna ask it as new question.

Comment: If you're using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, you can write `ä` directly; if you want to use `\"a` instead, you're not going to be able to use this shortcut (or you'll have to define it differently).